# showing multiple categories instead of unique while only restarting app in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple application of transactions,

here I have added a row of recent categories..

Its working fine but when I restart my app..its showing multiples same category than unique...

like I am doing following 5 transactions

1 : food
2 : tea
3 : tea
4 : tea
5 : food

its showing properly  Food Tea if I do these 5 entries at same time

but when I restart my app and start adding transaction,

its showing 5 categories in recent category like

food tea tea tea food

which I don't want...

I am using HIVE in this app...

completely failing where I am doing wrong...

Can't send all code as lengthy so sending necessary codes only

All data showing properly ..only getting wrong output in recent categories...

if it fails to compare category object, than y is it not showing double when I add entries without restarting..

Thanks in advance..

provider file

```
class TransactionProvider extends GetxController {
  List<TransactionModel> _transactions = [];

  Box<TransactionModel> transactionbox = Hive.box('ebook');

  TransactionProvider() {
    for (int x = 0; x < transactionbox.values.length; x++) {
      var trns = transactionbox.getAt(x);
      if (trns != null) _transactions.add(trns);
    }
  }

  void add_transaction(TransactionModel transactionmodel) {
    _transactions.add(transactionmodel);
    transactionbox.add(transactionmodel);
    update();
  }

 List<TransactionModel> get allTransactions {
    return _transactions;
  }


List<CategoryModel> get recentcategories {
    //copying data to local list
    List<TransactionModel> templist = List.from(_transactions);
    
    List<CategoryModel> recentcategorylist = [];
    
    //sorting data based on recent transaction
    templist.sort((TransactionModel a, TransactionModel b) =>
        b.date.compareTo(a.date));
        
    //used counter to get only last 5 unique category
    int counter=0;
        
    for(int x=0;x<templist.length;x++)
      {
        if(recentcategorylist.contains(templist[x].category))
          {
          }
        else
          {
            recentcategorylist.add(templist[x].category);
            counter++;
            if(counter==5)
              break;
          }
      }

      return recentcategorylist;

  }
```

creates-end file

```
class CreateSpend extends StatefulWidget {
  CreateSpend({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CreateSpend> createState() => _CreateSpendState();
}

class _CreateSpendState extends State<CreateSpend> {
  late bool showRecentCategory;  
  final controller=Get.put(TransactionProvider());
  @override
  void initState() {

  
    if (controller.recentcategories.length > 0)
      showRecentCategory = true;
    else
      showRecentCategory = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    txtdetail.dispose();
    txtamount.dispose();


  }

 


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add New Spend'),
        ),
        body:showRecentCategory == true
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text('Recent Categories',style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              )),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    showRecentCategory = false;
                                    setState(() {

                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Show All',))
                            ],
                          ),

                          //todo challenge add + icon after recent category
                          Container(
                            height: 100,
                            //color: Colors.grey,
                            child: GetBuilder<TransactionProvider>(
                              builder: (_) {

                                int number=controller.recentcategories.length;
                                print('builder:'+number.toString());
                                return number > 0
                                    ? ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount:
                                            number,
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          final cat = controller
                                              .recentcategories[index];
                                          return IconTile(
                                              catogymodel: cat,
                                              isselected:
                                                  selectedcategory == cat,
                                              ontap: () {
                                                selectedcategory = cat;

                                                setState(
                                                  () {},
                                                );
                                              });


                                        })
                                    : Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'No Recent Category Found',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                        ),
                                      );
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ):Container()
```

Comment: instead of this comparison if(recentcategorylist.contains(templist[x].category)) I use my udf for comparing Categorymodel's title property...it works...so Looks like it fails to compare object with object....but y...failing to understand